# R parameter DROP equivalent in Pandas

Tags: python, r, select, pandas

I would like to know what is the Python (Pandas) equivalent of the following R code:

```
outDataFrame <- myDataFrame[, rownames(inputDataFrame), drop=FALSE]
```

- row names of inputDataFrame are the same as the column names of myDataFrame.
- each row of myDataframe contains only one TRUE value (all other values are FALSE)

The result outDataFrame should have:

- same row names as myDataFrame row names
- only one column
- the values contained in that column should correspond to the colum name of myDataFrame for which the value is TRUE

I hope it is understandable...

Kind Regards

R.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do that is to use `numpy.dot`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame ( { 'A':[False, True], 'B':[True, False] }, index=['row1', 'row2'] )
>>> df
          A      B
row1  False   True
row2   True  False

[2 rows x 2 columns]

>>> pd.DataFrame( np.dot( df, df.columns ), index=df.index )
      0
row1  B
row2  A

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

alternatively:

```
>>> df.apply( lambda row: df.columns[row][0], axis=1 )
```

which outputs a `pd.Series`

Comment: Dot with Boolean and strings?? How does that even work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, using [np.argmax](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
In [55]: myDataFrame = pd.DataFrame([(True,False,False), (False,False,True), (False,False,True)], index=list('ABC'), columns=list('XYZ'))

In [56]: myDataFrame
Out[56]: 
       X      Y      Z
A   True  False  False
B  False  False   True
C  False  False   True

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [58]: pd.Series(myDataFrame.columns[np.argmax(myDataFrame.values, axis=1)], index=myDataFrame.index)
Out[58]: 
A    X
B    Z
C    Z
dtype: object
```

It's long but perhaps faster especially for large dataframes:

```
In [76]: myDataFrame2 = pd.concat([myDataFrame]*10000)

In [77]: %timeit pd.Series(myDataFrame2.columns[np.argmax(myDataFrame2.values, axis=1)], index=myDataFrame2.index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit pd.Series( np.dot( myDataFrame2, myDataFrame2.columns ), index=myDataFrame2.index )
100 loops, best of 3: 5.72 ms per loop

In [79]: %timeit myDataFrame2.apply(lambda row: myDataFrame2.columns[row][0], axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I think I was not clear in reality there are two dataframes involved:

myinput are df1 and df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(True,False,False), (False,False,True), (False,False,True)],    index=list('XYZ'), columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,1), (1,0,0), (1,1,1)], index=list('ABC'), columns=list('IJK'))
```

and the result should be same as:

```
   0
X  A
Y  C
Z  C
```